# Using the OR operator - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, logical-operators

I'm reading documentation about OR operator, it says:

> Most of the better DBMS will not even evaluate the second condition in
> an OR WHERE clausule if the first condition allready been met. (If the
> first condition is met, the row would be retrieved regardless the
> second condition).

```
SELECT prod_code, prod_price
FROM Articles
WHERE Code = '1' OR Code = '2'
```

Does this mean by documentation if Code = '1' query will return all values with '1' ignoring second condition WHERE Code = '2'.

I've tested this on SQL Server and it returns all values with 1 and all values with 2, so actually 2 rows.

So I'm bit confused here.

Comment: It means that if a row fulfils the condition of `Code = 1` then it won't evaluate the clause `Code = 2` for that row. That doesn't mean it stops checking the rest of the rows. The RDBMS will still return every row that fulfils either of those requirements.

Comment: @Larnu aaa for that row is the key! That part of sentence is missing in the book! :) Thanks mate! So if Code=1 is found RDBMS will go to next row, wont check same row twice! Thanks

Comment: This probably means conditions on *different* columns, e.g. `colA = 'foo' or colB between 1 and 5`

Answer (score 4):

The statement is simply about optimization, something called "short-circuiting".  It is saying that the comparison to `2` is not done when `1` matches the condition.  Because it does not matter what the comparison to `2` evaluates to.

You seem to be a bit confused by saying

> if Code = '1' query will return all values with '1' ignoring second condition WHERE Code = '2'.

`Code` is a column in each row, not an overall value that is constant for all rows.  (If so, it would be `@Code` in SQL Server, rather than `@Code`.)

For your example, though, you should be using `IN`:

```
WHERE Code IN ('1', '2')
```

If `Code` is numeric, the comparison values should not have single quotes.

Comment: I started learning mssql today, so I'm bit confused, but now it's clearer, author of book meant on one row, if value of Code in a row is 1, then why the heck do I need to check if value of Code is equal to 2 because it definatelly is not cuz I allready ound value of 1 there, so lets chek another row! RIght ?

Comment: @rokie12234 . . . Exactly.  This is a standard optimization across all programming languages (at least those that support conditional logic).  It is not particular to SQL.

Comment: @rokie12234 - it is not really because it knows that `Code` is definitely not equal to  2 rather it is because it does not matter what it is

Comment: "*If so, it would be `@Code` in SQL Server, rather than `@Code`*" Did you mean to use the same code value in both places in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

*Ripped from my original comment:* It means that if a row fulfils the condition of `Code = 1` then it won't evaluate the clause `Code = 2` for that row. That doesn't mean it stops checking the rest of the rows. The RDBMS will still return every row that fulfils either of those requirements.

So if we have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                        Code int,
                        SomeValue varchar(10));
INSERT INTO YourTable (Code,SomeValue)
VALUES (1,'asdkjsa'),
       (1,'asdojsa'),
       (2,'saohdsald'),
       (3,'sdfkjhsadk'),
       (3,'asdkjsagd');
```

If you were to run the query `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Code = 1 OR Code = 2;` then for the second 1st 2 rows, the `OR Code = 2` wouldn't be evaluated, as `Code = 1` has already evalutated true.

However, rather than using `WHERE Code = 1 OR Code = 2` you could use the more succinct operator `IN`: `WHERE Code IN (1,2)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean by documentation if Code = '1' query will return all
>   values with '1' ignoring second condition WHERE Code = '2'.

Every row has 1 value at the column `Code`.
When the table is scanned, the conditions in the `WHERE` clause are checked. 
If the rdbms you are using performs **short circuit evaluation**, then in the case of `OR`:
 if the value is say `'1'` then it does not also compare to `'2'` since it is not needed and moves on to the next row. 
If the value is not `'1'` then it performs another comparison to `'2'`. 
So to answer your question:
The rows with `Code = '2'` are not ignored. 
It's the **condition checking** that is ignored when **it is not needed**.

Answer (score 0):

Your example search condition is

```
Code = '1' OR Code = '2'
```

This is a boolean expression that is itself comprised of two sub boolean expressions combined with `OR`.

- `Code = '1'`
- `Code = '2'`

In SQL boolean expressions can have three possible truth values `true`, `false`, `unknown`.

When combining expressions with `AND` or `OR` truth tables can be used to expand out all the possible results. The truth table for `OR` is below.

```
╔═════════╦══════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║         ║ TRUE ║  FALSE  ║ UNKNOWN ║
╠═════════╬══════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ TRUE    ║ TRUE ║ TRUE    ║ TRUE    ║
║ FALSE   ║ TRUE ║ FALSE   ║ UNKNOWN ║
║ UNKNOWN ║ TRUE ║ UNKNOWN ║ UNKNOWN ║
╚═════════╩══════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

From reviewing the table above it can be seen that if you know that one of the sub expressions is true it does not matter what value the other expression has. The value of the overall combined expression will still be `true` so there's no need to even evaluate it.

SQL Server **can** do short circuit evaluation but [it doesn't guarantee that it will](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/).

Additionally it may come up with an execution plan where the two predicates are not even relevant to evaluate together. Potentially it could come up with a plan for the query in the question that contains an index seek operator with two seeks. One on `Code = '1'` and one on `Code = '2'`.

The separate predicate evaluation can now be removed from the execution plan as it is guaranteed that the combined results of these index seeks will match the `WHERE` clause and so there is no need to do any additional predicate evaluation beyond what would happen as part of these seeks.